# Nginx config remove .aspx extension in rewrite rule

Tags: nginx

I would like to ensure the below rewrite removes all .aspx extensions as well.

```
rewrite ^/cn/(.*)$ $scheme://www.domain.cn/$1 permanent;
```

I have something like this, but I also want to add to it and remove any .aspx file extensions.

Anyone suggest how I can do this, documentation seems a little lacking?

Comment: what exactly do you intend to *add* and what to *remove*?

Comment: Made an edit @Anatoly